# Maven control version of transitive dependencies of Spring Boot

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

I have a simple spring boot app that I am trying to add spring cloud consul to. Spring cloud consul relies on a newer version of spring boot. In my POM I have specified version `1.3.5.RELEASE` for all my spring boot artifacts.

The problem is that, even though version 1.3.5 is specified for `spring-boot-starter-web` it still downloads dependencies with version 1.2.3

Is there a way to have maven get the `1.3.5.RELEASE` for ALL spring boot artifacts, including transitive dependencies? I know I can explicitly list them all, but is there a better way?

Here is the POM depenency view from eclipse:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simple use correct parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

and remove versions from spring boot dependencies.

Comment: what if I don't want to use the parent? I tried adding dependency management, but had no luck.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317006/spring-boot-parent-pom-when-you-already-have-a-parent-pom

Comment: not quite. I am still having issues. Specifically it cannot find the internal class org/springframework/boot/Banner$Mode and it is still using spring boot jars with version 1.2.3 even though I specified in the dependency management 1.3.6

Comment: so what I ended up doing was making my parent specify spring boot starter as the parent and that worked