# Spring Integration with Kafka auto configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am trying to configure a Spring Boot application to consume Kafka messages. After adding:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

into my dependencies and with `@EnableKafka` and `@KafkaListener(topics = "some-topic")` annotations, I am getting the following error:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory' available
```

then I add the following configuration:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();

    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    return propsMap;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    return factory;
}
```

The error is gone. However, I think I should be able to autoconfigure this with the `spring.kafka.listener.*` properties, as the documentation suggests.

If I cannot, I would like to use an autowired `KafkaProperties`. However, to be able to use it, I am adding:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then it is available to import. When I try to use it as following:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
```

and in my method:

```
 return kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.annotation.DeterminableImports
.
```

which is a Maven dependency problem, I assume.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to configure a Kafka configuration without creating `@Bean`s but only with `application.properties`?
2. If not, how can I skip manually creating the required `Map` object as above but simply use `kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties()` without getting the above error(2nd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Maven issue, as I suspected. Basically, I work on a multi module project with the following structure:

```
────parent
    ├───parent.pom
    ├───module1
    |   └───module1.pom
    └───module2
        └───module2.pom
```

and my `parent.pom` had another `parent` element which was:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Basically replacing the above `parent` of `parent` with:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21318359) resolved all of the issues (Both autoconfiguration and being able to use `KafkaProperties`).

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://start.spring.io and select Kafka; he will build you a project skeleton all set to go

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafkademo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kafkademo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

props...

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=myGroup
```

App...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkademoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(KafkademoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        context.close();
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics="so8400in")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the listener to

```
@KafkaListener(topics="so8400in")
public void listen(String in) {
    System.out.println("Received message:" + in);
}
```

Then sent this message...

```
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic so8400in
test message for so42703487
```

...and on the console...

```
Received message:test message for so42703487
```

I can post the project on GitHub if you need further proof.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, this configuration as is won't work, with the above mentioned exceptions.

Comment: It works fine for me with the pom in my answer. No `@Bean`s needed, as you can see.

Comment: Could you try with `@EnableKafka` annotation? I believe you cannot receive messages with the above application.

Comment: Boot adds `@EnableKafka` during auto configuration. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java#L62) - I can assure you the above works (I tested it when I wrote it).

Comment: Please see my answer below. I understand it works, but it's not the answer to my problem. I appreciate your help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring Boot 2.7.0, the properties for Kafka consumers and producers have been restructured. Instead of using

> spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers

> spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers

, you need to use

> spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers

for both consumers and producers.

1. Open the application.properties file in your Spring Boot project.
2. Add the following property to configure the Kafka bootstrap servers:

   **spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092**