# Create both Spring and Spring Boot variants of an application using Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Our Existing Parent Project using spring 4.3.3.RELEASE, we are trying provide part of it as a Spring Boot Application and the other parts as a Spring.

To do this it seems we must create a Maven project that has two parents: our existing parent project and the Spring Boot parent. How can we do that?

Comment: See also [Spring Boot - parent pom when you already have a parent pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317006/spring-boot-parent-pom-when-you-already-have-a-parent-pom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the project into 3 parts, each with a POM. Most of the code goes in a "core" project. The other two are a "spring boot" and a "spring app" projects. Those two have the "core" as a dependency. The differences for Spring Boot and Spring go in those two projects.

Answer (score 0):

Each project can have but one parent POM.