# Spring Boot 2 Package not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Hello everybody i just started learning spring. I get the following error while maven packaging

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project pet-clinic-web: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Dropbox/yyy/spring/frameworkGuru/my-pet-clinic/pet-clinic-web/src/main/java/xxx/xxx/mypetclinic/controllers/OwnerController.java:[3,45] package xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Dropbox/yyy/spring/frameworkGuru/my-pet-clinic/pet-clinic-web/src/main/java/xxx/xxx/mypetclinic/controllers/OwnerController.java:[12,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OwnerService
[ERROR] location: class xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.controllers.OwnerController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Dropbox/yyy/spring/frameworkGuru/my-pet-clinic/pet-clinic-web/src/main/java/xxx/xxx/mypetclinic/controllers/OwnerController.java:[14,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class OwnerService
[ERROR] location: class xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.controllers.OwnerController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I have 2 modules *data* and *web*, i'm trying to access OwnerService(data->services) from OwnerController(web->controllers). I have added data module as a dependency in web pom

Intellij does not show errors, i can even list all owners it works fine but i try to package and error shows up. Here are some project files.

I tried with older spring boot version 2.0.3 the error is gone, but in 2.1.1 persists.

project pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-pet-clinic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <modules>
        <module>pet-clinic-data</module>
        <module>pet-clinic-web</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>my-pet-clinic</name>
    <description>My recode of spring pet clinic</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
        <start-class>xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.MyPetClinicApplication</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.5.3</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

data pom

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>my-pet-clinic</artifactId>
    <groupId>xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

web pom

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
        <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
        <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
            <groupId>xxx.xxx</groupId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

OwnerController

```
package xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.controllers;

import xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services.OwnerService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RequestMapping("/owners")
@Controller
public class OwnerController {

    private final OwnerService ownerService;

    public OwnerController(OwnerService ownerService) {
        this.ownerService = ownerService;
    }

    @RequestMapping({"","/","/index", "/index.html"})
    public String listOwners(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("owners",ownerService.findAll());

        return "owners/index";
    }
}
```

OwnerService

```
package xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services;

import xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.model.Owner;

public interface OwnerService extends CrudService<Owner, Long>{

    Owner findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

and OwnerServiceMap implementation

```
package xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services.map;

import xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.model.Owner;
import xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services.OwnerService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class OwnerServiceMap extends AbstractMapService<Owner, Long> implements OwnerService {

    @Override
    public Set<Owner> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Owner findById(Long id) {
        return super.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Owner save(Owner object) {
        return super.save(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Owner object) {
        super.delete(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        super.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Owner findByLastName(String lastName) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Code-repo](https://github.com/brutumi/my-pet-clinic)

Comment: OwnerService wasn't found, so should call OwnerServiceMap instead of OwnerService in your Controller.

Comment: i tried that, it shows the same error, it cannot find the whole package.       
`throws package xxx.xxx.mypetclinic.services does not exist`

Comment: Do not have classes in web projects you need elsewhere.

Comment: it would have been better if you can share repo link, if it is not an issue

Comment: https://github.com/brutumi/my-pet-clinic i rolled back to 2.0.3 it's gone now but on 2.1.1 persists

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>SPRING-BOOT-VERSION-HERE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

from your `pom.xml`.

For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21318359/2891426