# Making an executable jar out of spring boot MVC project serving content using JSP and a custom parent set in POM

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I had a Spring MVC project that I'm converting to spring boot. This project of mine cannot be given `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent because I need to keep a custom parent.
I solved this first issue by injecting `spring-boot-dependencies` in dependencyManagement.
I also need my project to embed a tomcat, so I've used `spring-boot-starter-web`. I need to use JSP so i've added the dependencies to `jstl` and `jasper`.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-loader -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Compiling the jar and launching the server using

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

correctly works. Now I'd like to make it work as executable jar, too.

I have read some documentation, posts, web pages, stack overflow questions, but I still cannot make it properly work.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243690/is-it-possible-with-spring-boot-to-serve-up-jsps-with-a-jar-packaging), reading the edited version of the accepted answer and the [github project](https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example) it looks very easy to make an executable jar out of a project having as parent `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Is it possible to make it work with a custom parent too?

I have already tried to follow these guidelines but it doesn't work with my project. 
I tried adding the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

both with and without the `execution` node

and the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <archive>
            <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
<!--    <archive>-->
<!--        <manifest>-->
<!--            <mainClass>my-boot-application</mainClass>-->
<!--            <springBootClasses>WEB-INF/classes/</springBootClasses>-->
<!--            <springBootLib>WEB-INF/lib/</springBootLib>-->
<!--        </manifest>-->
<!--    </archive>-->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

both with and without the `manifest` customized information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have incurred in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317006/spring-boot-parent-pom-when-you-already-have-a-parent-pom) listing all that is necessary to make a spring boot application using jsp, embedded tomcat and custom parent project work.

So, my pom.xml is now much readable and compact and looks much like the examples in the link.